# How to compare a time in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm making a game with levels and I am looking for a way to compare 2 times.
the first time is the time the player needed to complete the level the second time is a time that I choose. If the first time is less than the second time you get a star if it's higher you don't get a star. I have stored the 2 times in NSDates as you can see in my code below. I use an NSComparisonResult to compare the results. My problem is that the NSComparisonResult Result1 = 4294967295 instead of NSOrderedDescending or something like that.

```
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

    NSComparisonResult result1;
    NSComparisonResult result2;
    NSComparisonResult result3;
    // Create a date formatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.SSS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

    //has three possible values: NSOrderedSame,NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedAscending
    NSDate *level1ThreeStarRequirement = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:01.500"];
    NSDate *level1TwoStarRequirement = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:02.500"];
    NSDate *level1OneStarRequirement = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:02.500"];

    result1 = [timerDate compare:level1ThreeStarRequirement]; // comparing two dates
    result2 = [timerDate compare:level1TwoStarRequirement];
    result3 = [timerDate compare:level1OneStarRequirement];
    if (result1 == NSOrderedAscending){
        self.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star1.png"];
        self.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star2.png"];
        self.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star3.png"];
    }
    if (result2 == NSOrderedAscending){
        self.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star1.png"];
        self.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star2.png"];
        self.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noStar.png"];

    }
    if (result3 == NSOrderedDescending){
        self.star1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star1.png"];
        self.star2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noStar.png"];
        self.star3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noStar.png"];
    }
```

Thanks Matis

Comment: Print the value of all of the dates to start debugging the problem.

Comment: Gaah!! The time for receiving one star and two stars on the first level is the same! Outrageous!!

Comment: Hello Filip, that is because the time for receiving two stars must be lower than 2.500 the time to get 1 star must be higher than 2.500. So the players has always at least one star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you compare the dates using one of the built in functions of `NSDate`

```
– timeIntervalSinceDate:
– timeIntervalSinceNow
+ timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
– timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
– timeIntervalSince1970
```

this will give you a value in seconds. then your `result1` etc shouldnt be some mangled number, and you can compare the times directly to one another and order them like that

Comment: Thx but could you show me what I have to change in my code?

Comment: I've never worked with things like that.

Comment: `NSTimeInterval gap = [firstDate timeIntervalSince: secondDate];`  `NSTimeInterval` is a typdef for `double`.

Comment: I've just tried it and for some reason it sets the value of gap to 946684800.501478. Why is this happening?

Comment: I've found the problem and it works. Thanks to all!!!